# Django filter form appears by default as dropdown; change to checkbox

Tags: django, checkbox, filter, dropdown

I have a model defined like below in models.py

```
class ImageGrab(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    age=models.ForeignKey(Age, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gender=models.ForeignKey(Gender, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    masked=models.ForeignKey(Mask, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    withBackpack=models.ForeignKey(Backpack, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Filters for which are defined as below in filters.py:

```
class ImageFilterAge(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = ImageGrab
        fields = ['age']

###others similar to this 

class ImageFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = ImageGrab
        fields = ['age', 'gender', 'masked', 'withBackpack']
```

The view is like below defined in views.py

```
def images(request):
    imagelist = ImageGrab.objects.all()
    imagefilter = ImageFilter(request.GET, queryset=imagelist)
    agefilter = ImageFilterAge(request.GET, queryset=imagelist)
    genderfilter=ImageFilterGender(request.GET, queryset=imagelist)
    maskedfilter= ImageFilterMask(request.GET, queryset=imagelist)
    backpackfilter = ImageFilterBackpack(request.GET, queryset=imagelist) 
    return render(request, 'imglist.html', {'filter': imagefilter,'agefilter': agefilter.form, 'genderfilter':genderfilter.form, 'maskfilter':maskedfilter.form, 'backpackfilter':backpackfilter.form})
```

My template is like this, in imglist.html

```
<form method="get" name="search" id="search">
    {{ agefilter }} <br>
    {{ genderfilter }} <br>
    {{ maskfilter }} <br>
    {{ backpackfilter }} <br>
</form>
```

This is rendered by default as dropdown select form as given in image link below. I want to change this to say checkbox multiple select and/ or radio button for the filters.
[Filtering Using Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88A3P.png)

How to go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry for the multiple edits; could not post the correct picture hence had to edit a few times

Answer (score 1):

I combined the two solutions given by both users above, and got the solution thus:

**Filters.py**:

```
age = ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(queryset=Age.objects.all(),widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

**Models.py**

```
class Age(models.Model):
    ageChoices=(
        ('Child', 'Child'),
        ('Adult', 'Adult'),
        ('Old', 'Old'),
    )
    age = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=ageChoices)
```

What is good is that the filters seem to wok neatly on the data set as well.

Thanks to users Abdul Aziz Barkat & Vosem

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seeing how your models are set up you might want to create [a django custom form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/) on which you specify the fields and the input method for each field.

Although you also might want to rethink using Foreign Keys for something as simple as age, gender or withBackpack. You probably want to use other kinds of fields for those, like IntegerField or BooleanField

Comment: My implementation needs age to be categorized as "Child", "Adult" and "SeniorCitizen"; Gender and backpack options can be made to booleanfield

Comment: Then I might suggest a charfield with [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#choices) set. Makes it way cleaner instead of having another table.

Comment: Yes that is what i am attempting now; would come back in case of any issues. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can [customize the filter generation by specifying `filter_overrides`](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filterset.html#customise-filter-generation-with-filter-overrides) in the filter sets `Meta`. So for your use you can do something like below to set `CheckboxInput` as the widget to be used:

```
from django import forms
from django.db import models


class ImageFilterAge(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = ImageGrab
        fields = ['age']
        filter_overrides = {
            models.ForeignKey: {
                'filter_class': django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter,
                'extra': lambda f: {
                    'widget': forms.CheckboxInput,
                },
            },
        }
```

You can also explicitly define the filter field to be able to specify it's widget:

```
from django import forms


class ImageFilterAge(django_filters.FilterSet):
    age = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=Age.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxInput)
    class Meta:
        model = ImageGrab
        fields = ['age']
```

Comment: I get this instead of the dropdown on rendering the template:Age:
Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices. I used the second option you have specified.

Comment: First option does not give me checkboxes straight away either. Am I missing something, other than what is posted in the response given here?